# Comparing Date elements return wrong results - Swift

Tags: swift, date, core-data, calendar

I'm focusing on developing an app which deals with `Date` objects. I'm facing a problem related to comparing 2 `Date` object, I think I've identified the issue but can't really figure out a solution.

Consider the following:

```swift
extension Date{
    func nextDay(distance: Int = 1) -> Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: distance, to: self)!
    }
}

func generateTask(forProjects: [Project]){
        for project in forProjects {
            if tasks(forProject: project).isEmpty{
                var startDate = Date()
                var currentMilestone : Task = project.mostRecentMilestone
                var indexMilestone : Int = 0
                while startDate < project.lastMilestone.day!{ // Suppose last milestone differs 20 days from startDate
                    print("StartDate: \(startDate), Current: \(currentMilestone.day!)")
                    // Something
                    startDate = startDate.nextDay()
                }
            }
            else {
                print("Tasks already present")
            }
        }
        DB.shared.save()
    }
}
```

`lastMilestone.day` has been produced by this code:

```swift
lastMilestone.day = Date().nextDay(distance: 20)
```

Some clarification: `Project` is a structure which contains a `day: Date` attribute and `Task` is another object which contains the same attribute.
Suppose I'm incrementing the date by 1 day for every `while` cycle. The expected result would be:

```swift
StartDate: 2020-05-20 11:07:52 +0000, Current: 2020-06-09 11:07:49 +0000
StartDate: 2020-05-21 11:07:52 +0000, Current: 2020-06-09 11:07:49 +0000
StartDate: 2020-05-22 11:07:52 +0000, Current: 2020-06-09 11:07:49 +0000
...
StartDate: 2020-06-08 11:07:52 +0000, Current: 2020-06-09 11:07:49 +0000
*EXIT LOOP*
```

whereas I get

```swift
StartDate: 2020-05-20 11:07:52 +0000, Current: 2020-06-09 11:07:49 +0000
StartDate: 2020-05-21 11:07:52 +0000, Current: 2020-06-09 11:07:49 +0000
*EXIT LOOP*
```

Which means that comparision fail the second time. I've tried changing the code in this way:

```swift
//...
startDate = startDate.addingTimeInterval(3600*24)
//...
```

Which holds same result as before.
I'm starting to think this is related to `TimeZone` settings, or maybe the fact that `compareDate` is fetched from an entity contained in `CoreData`. 
As regards my first thought, I saw it is possible to setup the `Calendar.current` timezone manually but when I try to do it, I get a `read-only` error, which seems reasonable to me.
Any idea?

EDIT: Since I've verified that this code works on a clean project, I'm aware that I have to be more specific. Updated accordingly.

EDIT 2: As requested, here is the value of Date for `lastMilestone.day`

```swift
print("StartDate: \(startDate), Current: \(project.lastMilestone.day!)")

OUTCOME:

StartDate: 2020-05-20 17:59:48 +0000, Current: 2020-06-09 17:59:47 +0000
```

Comment: Did you copy your sample code (and only that!) into a fresh project and run it? Because it works as expected for me.

Comment: I will try in a fresh project right now

Comment: It works on a clean project. I will also link the full code in my old project

Comment: It would be good to see a log showing the value of project.lastMilestone.day, since that is the end condition for the loop.

Comment: @pbasdf edited as requested

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, I want to leave a solution to my question, which now I see could not be infered by it.

As I stated, the problem was linked to Core Data and my organisation of models.
In specific, `Task` entity was manipulated in the `//Something` part, but I didn't noticed that a particular relationship in Core Data model would influence the value of task stored in project.

To be more clear, the structure of my app is the following:
`Task` could be a normal task or a milestone. They held the same meaning, yet I know see they need to be 2 separate concept. In fact, both of them share a relationship with project, and project just take a reference of milestone. Yet, they share the same inverse relationship. This lead probably to a manipulation of `day` attribute of `Task` that invalidated the `while` loop in the answer.

*The solution was to separate entities and remove the inverse relationship.*

I'm really sorry for the poor accuracy in my question, I should have included an explaination of the problem in more detail.